# Stability of the given nonlinear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the system 
>   $$x'=-x+y^2,~~~~y'=x-2y+y^2.$$

(i). Show that $x=y$ is an orbit and is (for $x>0$) the unstable manifold through one of the critical points.

(ii). Show that $|x-y| \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for all the other orbits.

So by setting $x'=0$ and $y'=0,$ two critical points are found: $(0,0)$ and (1,1). I don't know how to go by and conclude what's being asked. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Let us start by the beginning: "(i). Show that $x=y$ is an orbit" What is the problem to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (partly) approach is doing what you have begun and looking for the equilibria

$$x=y^2\Rightarrow 2y^2-2y=2y(y-1)=0 \Rightarrow y_1=1,y_2=0 \Rightarrow (1,1),(0,0)$$
 and then looking at their stability and determining their stabl/unstable/center eigenspaces. 
$$Df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2y \\ 1 & -2+2y \end{pmatrix}$$

1) Let's look at $(0,0)$:
$$Df(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues $-1,-2$ with the stable eigenspace $E^s=\langle\binom{1}{1},\binom{0}{1}\rangle$ (these are the eigenvectors to the eigenvalues with negative real part).

2) Let's look at $(1,1)$: $$Df(1,1)=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues $-2,1$ with the stable eigenspace $E^s=\langle\binom{-2}{1} \rangle$ and unstable eigenspace $E^u=\langle\binom{1}{1} \rangle$. That means $x=y$ indeed describes the unstable eigenspace of the equilibrium $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=y$ you get $$x'=y'=-x+x^2.$$ This readily implies that the line $x=y$ is a union of orbits. Why? (But it is not an orbit.)

The remainder of the problem is just a matter of checking what are the directions on the line $x=y$.

Comment: Along the line $x=y$ the vector field is $(-x+x^2,-x+x^2)$ and has the same direction, say $(1,1)$. Thus, if you start on a point on the line, you will remain on the line. Since $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are equilibria these don't move and so you have $5$ orbits on the line $x=y$. Try to show that $(1,1)$ is hyperbolic (they do tell you that $x>0$...).